# Image.SelectActiveFrame memory problem

Tags: c#, image, memory-leaks

I'm writing a control to show images.
My problem comes out using Image class on multipage TIFFs.
I use this (I post only relevant code) at the beginning:

```
Image img;
int pages;
img = Bitmap.FromFile(filename);
pages = img.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
```

then, when the user wants to show a different page:

```
public override Image GetPage(int page)
{
    if (page < 1 || page > pages) return null;
    try
    {
        #if !TEST
            img.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, page - 1);
            return new Bitmap(img);
        #else
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            img.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, page - 1);
            img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            Image ret = Image.FromStream(ms);
            ms.Flush();
            ms.Dispose();
            return ret;
        #endif
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        "Tiff GetPage error: {0}".ToDebug(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using `img.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, page - 1);` (in both versions) about 7MB are allocated in memory and those are never freed (even exiting the method)!!!
If I goes to next page 7MB are allocated and not freed **everytime**, while going back (on an already visited pages) previously allocated memory is used.
To give you an example: think Task Manager reports my app is using x MB; going one page forward memory increases to x + y (after `SelectActiveFrame()`) + z (`Image ret = ...`). Well, I should have x + z (y part should be zero or GC collected exiting the method), but obviously that's not what happens, even calling `GC.Collect` manually.
Going back to a previously visited page, memory increases effectively only with z, as expected.
I find it terrible (think about a file with 80 pages...), but how can I force img object to free allocated memory? Am I doing something wrong?
I've already thought closing and reopening img, but speed is not good.
Thanks to everybody

Comment: There is no call to Image.Dispose() visible anywhere in the snippet.  So it is probably missing.  Required to avoid the build-up.

Comment: @Hans, yes, I know. Look at the comment I wrote to user965487. If I call `img.Dispose()`, next time user wants a page I have to call `img = Bitmap.FromFile()` again and with multipage TIFFs really big (hundreds pages) this could lead to a new speed problem.. anyway I try and let you know

Comment: @Hans Passant: I tried another solution (the one you suggested me, even if I didn't want to walk that way) and that's a solution for _strange_ memory allocation. Just a question: why `img.SelectActiveFrame()` has this behaviour? Why MS team thought this class to behave in this way? I know that they are certainly right, so I'd like to understand the reason :) Thanks. Ah, I wrote an answer to explain better problem and solution. Do you agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you're not destroying the used controls at every possible point.
I think you might need to test this - but make sure that you're disposing all the used controls.

ie. `ImageControlUsed.Dispose();`

Comment: _I've already thought closing and reopening img, but speed is not good_: if I use `img.Dispose()`, when the user want to get next page I have to reopen img again using `img = Bitmap.FromFile(filename);` and I think this could be really slow on big files (I have multipage TIFFs with hundreds pages!!)

Comment: I didn't want to dispose img everytime, but that's the only solution I found. So I accept your answer because... well, you told me to do that :)

Comment: Aye, unfortunately I have looked over all possible leads. It seems like there is no other possible way of doing this. They should really make a .flush(); for the next releases in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use new Bitmap(img) because it will force the system to create new memory for a new Bitmap object using 32-bit color by default.

You can just use var bitmap = (Bitmap)img; to retrieve a Bitmap object for that page.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question after trying different solutions and accept soluzion given by user965487 because at the end he was right (thanks to Hans Passant too).
If you have a class (call it QV) similar to this

```
public class QV
{
    Image img;
    int pages;

    public QV(filename) {
       img = Bitmap.FromFile(filename);
       pages = img.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
    }

    ~QV() {
        img.Dispose();
        img = null;
    }

    public Image GetPage(int page) {
        if (page < 1 || page > pages) return null;
        img.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, page - 1);
        return new Bitmap(img);
    }
}
```

then every time you call `GetPage(...)` your memory will grow not only for the size of returned image, but also for `img.SelectActiveFrame(...)` statement. I don't know why and how, but it happens. Releasing returned image and calling frees memory for image size, not for the amount taken from *SelectActiveFrame()* (anyway this memory is not duplicated if you return on a previously seend page).
So you'd better open and close the image everytime, like this:

```
public class QV
{
    Image img;
    int pages;

    public QV(filename) {
       img = Bitmap.FromFile(filename);
       pages = img.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
       img.Dispose();
    }

    public Image GetPage(int page) {
        if (page < 1 || page > pages) return null;
        img = Bitmap.FromFile(filename);
        img.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, page - 1);
        Image ret = Bitmap(img);
        img.Dispose();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Payload for opening and disposing image everytime user requests a new page is really nothing compared to dangerous memory allcation done with first solution.
I hope someone needs this.